# why cant this bubble sort this list in java to output alphabetically?

Tags: java, sorting

What variables am I supposed to use with this bubble sort? I tried many times to look up tutorials online but, they all mainly showed how to do this with a smaller list of numbers and not a scanned string file. I just need to have two flight routes considered equal if they have the same source and destination airport code and if they are not equal, the comparison should be made based on the source airport code alphabetically. I really need help on this one its hurting my brain and I know this solution is probably extremely simple. I went ahead and highlighted the code for bubble sorting that needs help.

```
public class FlightRouteDriver 
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            String routeFile = "FlightRouteData-US.txt";

            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            ArrayList<Comparable> flRouteList = new ArrayList<Comparable>();

            BufferedReader br = null;
            String line = "";
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(routeFile));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] dataSet = line.split(";");
                    FlightRoute flRoute = createFlightRoute(dataSet);
                    flRouteList.add(flRoute);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Uploaded data file contains " + flRouteList.size() + " flight routes.");

            //sorting list of flight route
            System.out.println("Bubble Sort Algorithm running ..." );
            BubbleSort(flRouteList);
            System.out.println("Flight route data sorted..." );

            //Getting user input on source and destination airport codes
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Departure Airport code: ");
            String departureAirport = userInput.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Destination Airport code: ");
            String destinationAirport = userInput.next();
            userInput.close();

            //creating a target flight for search
            String[] target = new String[13];

            target[0]="";
            target[1]="0";
            target[2]=departureAirport;
            target[3]="";
            target[4]="01:00";
            target[5]="0";
            target[6]=destinationAirport;
            target[7]="";
            target[8]="01:00";
            target[9]="0";
            target[10]="N";
            target[11]="0";
            target[12]="";

            FlightRoute targetRoute = createFlightRoute(target);

            ArrayList<Comparable> found =  linearSearch (flRouteList, targetRoute);

            System.out.println("\n***Flight Route search result***");

            if(found == null)
                System.out.println("Flight route not found.");
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i<found.size(); i++)
                    System.out.println("Flight Routes found. Details are below.\n" + found.get(i));
            }

        }//end of main method



        //  -------------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Creates a FlightRoute object using specified String array object.
        //  -------------------------------------------------------------------
        private static FlightRoute createFlightRoute(String[] dataSet)
        {
            String airline = dataSet[0];
            int airlineID = Integer.parseInt(dataSet[1]);
            String sourceAirportCode = dataSet[2];
            String sourceAirportCity = dataSet[3];
            Time sourceCityDepartureTime = Time.valueOf(dataSet[4]+":00");
            int sourceAirportID = Integer.parseInt(dataSet[5]);
            String destinationAirportCode = dataSet[6];
            String destinationAirportCity = dataSet[7];
            Time destinationCityArrivalTime = Time.valueOf(dataSet[8]+":00");
            int destinationAirportID = Integer.parseInt(dataSet[9]);
            char codeshare = dataSet[10].charAt(0);
            int stops = Integer.parseInt(dataSet[11]);
            String equipment = dataSet[12];

            FlightRoute flRoute = new FlightRoute(airline,airlineID,sourceAirportCode,
                    sourceAirportCity,sourceCityDepartureTime, sourceAirportID,
                    destinationAirportCode,destinationAirportCity, destinationCityArrivalTime,
                    destinationAirportID,codeshare, stops, equipment );

            return flRoute;
        }//end of createFlightRoute method


        //  -------------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Sorts the specified list of objects using a bubble sort algorithm.
        //  -------------------------------------------------------------------




         static void BubbleSort(ArrayList<Comparable> flRouteList) {
            String t;
            for(int i=0; i<flRouteList.length; i++) {
                for(int j=0; j<flRouteList.length-1-i; j++) {
                if(Comparable[j].compareTo(dataSet[j+1])>0) {
                    t= array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = t;
                    }
                }
              }
            }
```

Comment: If I figure this one out myself I will definitely post my results to help others out if they are experiencing similar issues

Comment: Consider writing unit tests for the bubble sort method.

Comment: OK i just changed the method to use this instead and it seems to be a step in the right direction ::::
static void BubbleSort(ArrayList<Comparable> flRouteList) {

Comment: You're trying to sort based on the value in the `ArrayList`, but you don't use it for anything other than a for limit, i.e., you don't do anything with it. The variables you need to use are the elements contained in `flRouteList`.